# RXCPP: Timeout on blocking function

Tags: c++11, rxcpp

Consider a blocking function: this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(3000));

I'm trying to get the following behavior:

```
Trigger Blocking Function               

|---------------------------------------------X
```

I want to trigger the blocking function and if it takes too long (more than two seconds), it should timeout.

I've done the following:

```
my_connection = observable<>::create<int>([](subscriber<int> s) {
    auto s2 = observable<>::just(1, observe_on_new_thread()) |
    subscribe<int>([&](auto x) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(3000));
        s.on_next(1);
    });
}) |
timeout(seconds(2), observe_on_new_thread());
```

I can't get this to work. For starters, I think s can't on_next from a different thread.

So my question is, what is the correct reactive way of doing this? How can I wrap a blocking function in rxcpp and add a timeout to it?

Subsequently, I want to get an RX stream that behaves like this:

```
Trigger                Cleanup

|------------------------X
                           (Delay)   Trigger           Cleanup
                                       |-----------------X
```

Comment: Another way I thought this can be done is:

`auto connection = timeout.amb(blocking_function_observable)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question! The above is pretty close.

Here is an example of how to adapt blocking operations to rxcpp. It does [libcurl polling](https://github.com/kirkshoop/twitter/blob/master/rxcurl.h#L15..L40) to make http requests.

The following should do what you intended.

```
auto sharedThreads = observe_on_event_loop();

auto my_connection = observable<>::create<int>([](subscriber<int> s) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(3000));
        s.on_next(1);
        s.on_completed();
    }) |
    subscribe_on(observe_on_new_thread()) |
    //start_with(0) | // workaround bug in timeout
    timeout(seconds(2), sharedThreads);
    //skip(1); // workaround bug in timeout

my_connection.as_blocking().subscribe(
    [](int){}, 
    [](exception_ptr ep){cout << "timed out" << endl;}
);
```

- `subscribe_on` will run the `create` on a dedicated thread, and thus `create` is allowed to block that thread.
- `timeout` will run the timer on a different thread, that can be shared with others, and transfer all the `on_next`/`on_error`/`on_completed` calls to that same thread.
- `as_blocking` will make sure that `subscribe` does not return until it has completed. This is only used to prevent `main()` from exiting - most often in test or example programs.

EDIT: added workaround for bug in `timeout`. At the moment, it does not schedule the first timeout until the first value arrives.

EDIT-2: `timeout` bug has been fixed, the workaround is not needed anymore.

Comment: Hi Kirk, thanks for your input on this. I ran the code snippet you suggested. It seems the `on_next` is triggering before the `on_error`. My suspicion is the `this_thread::sleep_for()` is blocking the timeout from starting the internal timer. If the `s.on_completed` is removed, an `on_next` fires followed by `on_error` from the timeout.

Comment: that is what I get for not trying this first. I found a bug in the timeout operator, I have updated the answer with a workaround for the bug.

Comment: I merged a PR that fixes `timeout`. The workaround is not needed anymore! Keeping the workaround will have some minor overhead, but otherwise will still work the same with the fixed `timeout`